# ng-grid inside modal window just works the fist time the modal is open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, ng-grid

i have a grid inside a modal window (has to be there, since my client really wants it that way), when the modal is open for the first time the rows in the grid can be selected,the selected items are shown in a div on the parent window, everything seems to be fine, but then when the modal window is closed and open again, the rows in the ng-grid are frozen, i cant deselect the old rows or select new ones. The idea is that he can add or remove details by selecting or deselecting rows in the ng-grid, but it only adds, and just the first time the modal window is open.

```
$scope.catalogOptions = {
        data: 'catalog',
        selectedItems: $scope.selectedDetails,
        columnDefs: [
            { field: "Num", displayName: 'NUM', width:"10%"},
            { field: "Type", displayName: 'TYPE', width:"90%"}],
        multiSelect: true,
        afterSelectionChange: function(item, event){
            if($scope.selectedDetails.length!=0){
                $scope.sdetails=$scope.selectedDetails;
            }
        }
    };
    $scope.sdetails=null;
```

this is my ng-grid definition in my controller, i also must say the modal window with the ng-grid is being called from another modal window (my client ask for that), basically the structure is "main page>add record modal>add detail modal", im using this plugin http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/bs3.html and calling the modals from buttons with data-toggle and href

is what im trying to do even posible? =(

Comment: It's difficult to answer without actual example. Please provide with the jsfiddle or plnkr example.

Comment: im sorry im quite new to webdevelopment and my english is not that good didnt find the plugins i needed to fully show my problem in plnkr,but i decide to drop the bootstrap plugin from jschr and pick the one made for angular, everything seems fine now, tnks for your time, seems like the modal windows where unbinding the model

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see how many times the afterSelectionChange method is being called? If you are selecting a row for the second time this callback is called twice, once for the previously selected row and once for the newly selected row.

```
    afterSelectionChange: function(item, event){
        if(item.selected) { //<-- only execute the below for the selected row
            if($scope.selectedDetails.length!=0){
                $scope.sdetails=$scope.selectedDetails;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i needed this to work in both cases, my code work like intended just the first time the modal window was opened. After more inspection, my datepickers inside the modal window were also working just the first time the modal was opened, so i changed my aproach since it looks that something was unbinding the model. After using the boostrap.ui modal my datepickers start working fine on every time i open the modal, and instead of open another modal for the ng-grid i just place it somewhere inside the first modal to work as a checklist for the client to choose details.